# The percentage of data below a certain threshold in a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The size of stones used in a concrete blend are normally distributed, with a mean diameter of 19.5mm and a standard Deviation of 1.8mm

a) what is the probability that a stone taken at random will have a diameter greater than 18mm

b) the smallest 15.15% of the stones are to be removed by passing them over a sieve. What size should the holes in the sieve be?

(ie: below what size will the stones be rejected)

I'm at a loss, please help.

Comment: For $a)$ just calculate $P(X>18)=1-P(X\leq 18)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{18-19.5}{1.8} \right)=1-\Phi\left( -0.8333\right) =\Phi\left( 0.8333\right)$, where $\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Hint for b): For which $z$ is $\Phi(z)=0.1515$? And then, as before use $z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: What is phi(z)?